# json_encode return integer values on windows and string on linux

Tags: php, laravel, json

I've this strange problem showing up lately. I'm currently developing on a Windows environment while deploying on a Linux server, I know that isn't ideal but I can't do much about it at this stage.

All I'm doing is getting the data from database and then returning a JSON response of the resulting array, but the result is different causing problem in my front-end app.

I'm getting this on windows:

```
{
    "id":40,
    "name":"test"
}
```

and this on Linux:

```
{
     "id":"40",
     "name":"test"
}
```

I'm actually using Laravel framework and so the syntax is simply this:

```
$user = User::find($id);
return Response::json($user->toArray());
```

Which behind the scene is doing this:

```
$this->data = json_encode($data);
```

So unluckily I don't have a hook where to set `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option.

Before refactoring my code, is there a way to force `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` on all `json_encode` calls? I'm using the same database to fetch the data so I guess it could be a *platform-related* problem?

**EDIT:**

Further investigations made me think that the guilty may be the database drivers.
If I dump the data on windows I'm getting this:

```
 array
      'id' => int 40
      'name' => string 'test' (length=4)
```

while on Linux it's:

```
array
     'id' => string '40' (length=2)
     'name' => string 'test' (length=4)
```

Comment: what version php is? I'll take a look into php-src for details.

Comment: Well I have 5.3.9 on Windows and 5.4.17 on Linux but I don't think it's a PHP problem, but more a database's driver problem. I've added the dump of the data returned from database to my question.

Comment: Ok, then maybe you say what DB you use and what drivers you use?

Comment: I'm using a Mysql database and querying it via PDO. Well I'm not querying it directly, I'm using the built-in ORM library from Laravel Framework, Eloquent.

Comment: PDO uses MySQL API driver. Only mysqlnd provides correct data types. So querying integer return integer. Another drivers return all data as string. Also you can check PDO does not use statement prepare emulation.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, now the things get clearer. Looking at phpinfo() in my Windows system php uses mysqlnd while on Linux's server it uses mysql. As this is a shared host I don't think I can do much about that, I just have to refactor my code to be sure that the values are formatted correctly and can be consumed safely by my client's javascript code. Thanks again!

Comment: Just put my last comment as answer for this question.

Comment: I know this is an old conversation, but I found that if you're using Laravel 4 with blade, you can use {{{ json_encode($arrayList) }}} which will keep it as an integer. It works on Linux. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel uses PDO and PDO uses MySQL driver. It's mysql or mysqlnd.

Only mysqlnd provides correct data types. So querying integer return integer.
Another drivers return all data as string.
Also you can check that PDO does not use statement prepare emulation.