# Javascript sum (+) different result windows and linux

Tags: javascript, linux

This code return different result, why ?

```
$.getJSON('/myfile.php?year='+anno , function(data) {
    var listKey = [];
    var values = [];
    var mySum = 0 ;
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
         listKey.push([key]); 
         values.push(val);
         mySum = mySum + val ;                   
    });
});
```

On windows console.log(data) return : Object {01:3000, 02:1500}

On linux console.log(data) return :

```
Object
05: "3000"
06: "1500"
__proto__: Object
__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() { [native code] }
__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() { [native code] }
__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() { [native code] }
__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() { [native code] }
constructor: function Object() { [native code] }
hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }
propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() { [native code] }
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }
toString: function toString() { [native code] }
valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }
get __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }
set __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }
myfile.php:275
```

On windows server mySum = 4500

On linux server mySum = 030001500

I fix this changing this part :

```
mySum = Number(mySum) + Number(val) ;
```

and now the result is equal in both servers but i dont understand why this difference.

Comment: It could be a problem in the `myfile.php`, where the JSON gets generated.

Comment: @thefourtheye the php file is the same, why windows sum correct and linux concat the values ?

Comment: But the responses are not. Please post the two HTTP responses, including all headers and the complete body

Comment: A server configuration doesn't affected code executed on client side (like JS), unless some headers are messed up. Please post your headers information here.

Comment: It looks like one server returns `{"01":3000, "02":1500}` while the other returns `{"01":"3000", "02":"1500"}`. Even if the PHP is the same, it might use different dynamic types? You might want to post the PHP code as well.

Comment: Given @Bergi's comment, it could be [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944239/json-encode-return-integer-values-on-windows-and-string-on-linux) (difference in database drivers on different OSes). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079320/php-pdo-mysql-returns-integer-columns-as-strings-on-ubuntu-but-as-integers-o) looks to also be the same, and goes into more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the output I'd say that the problem is that `val` is being treated as a string since "0" + "3000" + "1500" will return "0300015000".  Have a really close look at the JSON being produced to make sure that strings aren't being returned -- that the numbers you want to sum up aren't wrapped in quotes.

As to why this only happens on one OS vs another, I think that's a red herring.

Comment: It could be database drivers. I linked two SO questions dealing with what seems to be the same issue in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912771/javascript-sum-different-result-windows-and-linux#comment34971213_22912771).